# Are partial views a good way to restrict user access?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have used partial views in the past to split up large views. However are they a good way to restrict user access? Can the partial view be accessed at all by unauthorised users in my current setup.

```
View:
    @if (ViewBag.UserType == 1)
    {
        @Html.Partial("PartialView/_StandardUser");
    }
    else if (ViewBag.UserType == 2)
    {
        @Html.Partial("PartialView/_AdminUser");
    }

Controller:
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.UserType = 2;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: IMO deciding what to show inside view is not a good idea, better decide it on server side. Also t depends what are you showing. Is there any common parts between standard user's view and admin's?

Comment: If you have some buttons or parts that you [don't] want to show on your view, just check if that content is visible or not (for current user) on your action method.

Comment: @SeM The view code runs on the server side anyway

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I meant decide in controller.

Comment: "Good" is not a technical term so the answers here are mostly opinion-based. There is nothing inherently insecure about it. If you're worried, add an additional UserType check within the partial view itself.

Answer (score 1):

Razor view is rendered on server. So the end user sees only a result of the logic. If you are not depending on some external parameters (sent by client/user) ex. query/route/other parameters which indicates privilages it is ok (of cours if you are authorizing/authenticating users like it should be - using authorize attibute and then regarding on the privilage do some logic). However if those 2 are totaly separate (not using same part of html which is not a part of layout) I would rather split them as I can't see any benefits here of doing logic in the view.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can restrict user access and the partial views can't be accessed by unauthorized users.

On the other side the better approach will be using the user roles to restrict the access. For example:

```
View:
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
    {
        @Html.Partial("PartialView/_AdminUser");
    }
    else if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("StandardUses"))
    {
        @Html.Partial("PartialView/_StandardUser");
    }

Controller:
    [Authorize(Users = "Administrators,StandardUses")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> However are they a good way to restrict user access?

I would say no, not from a security stand point but a maintainability stand point.  Views should be an Html representation of data.  Mixing logic directly in a view should be limited as much as possible simply for maintainability.

So the following logic

```
@if (ViewBag.UserType == 1)
{
  Html.RenderPartial("PartialView/_StandardUser");
}
else if (ViewBag.UserType == 2)
{
  Html.RenderPartial("PartialView/_AdminUser");
}
```

Could simply be replaced with:

view:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("UserView");
```

controller method:

```
public class SomeController
{
  public ActionResult UserView()
  {
    if (ViewBag.UserType == 1)
    {
      return Partial("PartialView/_StandardUser");
    }
    else if (ViewBag.UserType == 2)
    {
      return Partial("PartialView/_AdminUser");
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
  }
}
```

> Can the partial view be accessed at all by unauthorised users in my current setup.

If the code you have provided is the only code that returns those Partials, then the answer is *yes*.  However, it's logic is hidden in a view, which I would never recommend.

Comment: How can I then implement the parent of the partial views? For example I have the partialviews in a subfolder and I want them to be contained within the parent Index view